# Attach class to map area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have this code that when the word Level 2 is clicked the tab page changes.

```html
<div class="wlt_tab_object"><a href="#t2">Level 2</a></div>
```

I am desperately trying to get the same thing to happen from an image map area.

area shape="circle" coords="75,101,24" href="#t2" class="wlt_tab_object"
 - doesn't work.

Can anybody suggest how I may be able to get this to work?

Rerards Leigh.

The page in question is at http://krplaza.com.au/

Basically what I am trying to achieve is to get the Lift Buttons to behave like the Level 1, Level 2, Level 3 links.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Can you share the JavaScript with us? Perhaps you could mkae a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit out of my depth here..

Ist This it?

<script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){ jQuery('.wlt_tab_object a').click(function (e) {  e.preventDefault(); jQuery(this).tab('show');  equalheight('.tab-content .grid_style .item .thumbnail');  }) })
    
   jQuery(window).load(function() {
     equalheight('.tab-content .grid_style .item .thumbnail');
   });
   
   jQuery(window).resize(function(){
     equalheight('.tab-content .grid_style .item .thumbnail');
   });
    
    </script>

Comment: Yes, that is it. It also looks like some of your HTML is missing though. Could you edit your question and post a link to the page in question? It seems like there is a lot of code, and it's hard to know what we need to answer your question if you're not a programmer.